# Python - For loop finishing before it is supposed to

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently executing tasks via a thread pool based on a for loop length, and it is ending its execution when it is not supposed to (before end of loop). Any ideas why? Here is the relavent code:

```
from classes.scraper import size
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Do something")
    size = size()
    pool = Pool(processes=50)
    with open('size.txt','r') as file:
        asf = file.read()
        for x in range(0,1000000):
            if '{num:06d}'.format(num=x) in asf:
                continue
            else:
                res = pool.apply_async(size.scrape, ('{num:06d}'.format(num=x),))
```

Here is the console output (I am printing out the values inside `size.scrape()`.

```
...
...
...
013439
013440
013441
013442
013443

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: may be file ended?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JC1 what are you trying to do with this statement
`if '{num:06d}'.format(num=x) in asf:
                continue`
specially that format.

Comment: @Sheshnath I am forcing the variable x which is passed into ```size.scrape()``` to be six digits. I am saying if it already exists in ```size.txt``` then skip it

Comment: @JC1 Not sure what's there is the `size.txt`, it's possible that the `size.txt` has all the number greater than `013443` and your for loop ends up in continue block.

Comment: @Sheshnath basically ```size.txt``` contains all the numbers in separate lines that have met a certain condition in ```size.scrape()```.  Could you elaborate on why if its greater than ```013443``` then it freezes in the continue?

Comment: @JC1 I meant, `size.txt` contains all the numbers between `013443` and `1000000` and that may be the reason you `if` condition is always executing and eventually your for loop ends.